# Hide context menu in TaskBar Icon after click "Exit"

Tags: c#, wpf

When I click the exit button in context menu it still appears until the method finish.

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon Name="TrayIcon" IconSource="Icon.ico" ToolTipText="text" Visibility="Visible"  MenuActivation="LeftOrRightClick">
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu">
                    <ContextMenu.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource MenuTPL}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ContextMenu.Style>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="LogIn" Click="LogIn_Click" Header="points"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="Exit" Click="Exit_Click" Header="exit"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

And the c# code is:

```
private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TrayIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;  
        TrayIcon.ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;         
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

I can't put the `shutdown` to backgroud. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave the event handler. Use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`for it.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=> { Application.Current.Shutdown(); }));
```